# How can a .NET Framework desktop-application gain elevated privileges?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.8

### Goal

The goal is to trigger the UAC dialog and allow the app to temporarily elevate privileges to perform activities that require admin access, but not require the entire application to run with elevated privileges.

### Processes have fixed permissions, right?

If I remember right, the "process" model at the operating system level requires that a process finish with the same privileges it starts with (ie. cannot be changed).

So the only way to 'elevate' is to start a new process.  No problem with that - the process can do what it needs to then terminate, with inter-process-communication as required.  But what's the 'modern .NET way' to get the process to start?

### Does a declarative option *still* exist?

There are *old* articles ( eg. this [C# Corner article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator-using-uac) for VS 2012 ) that discuss adding a declarative security condition in the `app.manifest`:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

... however, I can't follow the instructions in the article ... adding an Application Manifest *at all* isn't a thing in VS 2019, it seem (VS 2019, .NET Framework 4.7.2, Console App):

[image: No option to add a manifest]

### Or is a programmatic option the only way?

I believe I could use a `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` to specify `.verb = "runas"` to start the process.  Is there a better alternative?

Comment: to add the manifest, go to project, add new element, select application Manifest file. Edit the file and you'll find instructions inside.
add `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
Effect: Starting the application will trigger UAC and the whole thing will run with administrator priviledge. All child processes will do as well.

Comment: @Mahobo yes, that's what I've read, but the dialog for `<right-click-project> -> Add > New Item ... (Ctrl+Shift+A)` does not include the promised option for Application Manifest.  I have edited the question to show the pic

Comment: it's there with VS2019. When I start a new project (Forms or console), I press SHIFT+CTRL+A and the manifest is available.
Have no idea, why it's missing at your side

Comment: @Mahobo thanks for asserting that it should be there ... investigating further, I found that I had not ticked '.NET Desktop Development' in the VS installer!  That is fixed now!